# Combining several text files into a single csv

Tags: shell-script, csv

**Input files:**

**File: Article1.txt:**

```
paragraph1 It is a long established fact that a reader will......

paragraph2 It is a long established fact that a reader will......

paragraph3 It is a long established fact that a reader will......
```

**File: Article2.txt:**

```
It is a long established fact that a reader will......

It is a long established fact that a reader will......

It is a long established fact that a reader will......
```

**File: Article3.txt:**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing....... 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing......

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.......
```

**Desired Output:**

File: example.csv:

```
column1     column2                     column3
Article1    paragraph1 It is a......    paragraph2 It is a....... 
Article2    paragraph1 It is a......    paragraph2 It is a....... 
Article3    Lorem I.......              Lorem I.......
```

Comment: `CSV` represents `Comma Separated Values` and your desired output contains no commas.  When dealing with this kind of task, you also need to clarify how you'll treat lines that do not match the lines from other files as well as a proper solution which would allow commas in the input.

Comment: Also note that your sample input doesn't match your sample output in any way to make sense of your logic.

Comment: To rephrase what Julie said, please explain what you want, and rewrite your samples to fit with your explanation and to be totally unambiguous.

Comment: It is not so obvious (as [se] doesn't display them as such) that there a tab characters between the columns. Do you want the columns to be aligned by multiple tabs, or with spaces and a final "separation" tab. Is the input guaranteed to have no tabs of it own, if not, how should the tabs align (8 positions, 4 positions etc)?

Answer (score 1):

just a wild guess

```
 awk 'BEGINFILE { printf "%s",FILENAME}
                { printf ",%s",$0 ;}
      ENDFILE { printf "\n" ;}' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

this will turn file to csv (but unquoted), file being converted to one line.

replace `",%s"` by `"\t%s"` to use tab.

Answer (score 0):

First combine all the text files:

```
cat Article1.txt Article2.txt Article3.txt > Result.txt
```

Then convert the text file to CSV:

```
 (echo "Col1;Col2;Col3" ; cat Result.txt) | sed 's/;/<tab>/g' > file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %files=(); my @files=(); my $currentfile=''; my $maxcols=1;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  # a hash such as %files is inherently unordered, so store each
  # filename we process in @files, in the order that we see them.
  if ($currentfile ne $ARGV) {
    $currentfile = $ARGV ;
    push @files, $currentfile;
  };

  # choose between the entire input line or the first 20 chars:
  #push @{ $files{$currentfile} }, $_ ;
  push @{ $files{$currentfile} }, substr($_,0,20) . '...';

  # keep track of the largest number of columns in the %files
  # hash-of-arrays. in other words, the largest number of lines in any
  # input file.
  if (@{ $files{$currentfile} } > $maxcols) {
    $maxcols = @{ $files{$currentfile} } 
  };
};

print join("\t", map {"column$_"} @{[1..$maxcols+1]} ),"\n";

foreach my $f (@files) {
  print join("\t",$f,@{ $files{$f} }),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
Article1    paragraph1 It is a l... paragraph2 It is a l... paragraph3 It is a l...
Article2    It is a long establi... It is a long establi... It is a long establi...
Article3    Lorem Ipsum is simpl... Lorem Ipsum is simpl... Lorem Ipsum is simpl...
```

Note: the output is tab separated.  The fields don't line up visually with the column headings because they're longer than the default tab width.